# Compatibility merge workflow in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, merge

Besides "default" I have a "compat" branch in my repository which exists to support older versions of Python. So the default workflow is that I implement features in "default", merge to "compat" and fix all compatibility issues there. This is a typical patch workflow and works really fine.

But what if I want to introduce some changes which shouldn't be in the "compat" (e.g. features which won't work on older versions). To not break my default workflow I would have to merge "default" and then backout all changesets which shouldn't be in this branch in the first place.

Is there any better approach to deal with this issues (which doesn't break my default workflow)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new branch/bookmark off the default branch for your changest that you don't want in compat.  When you're done, you can merge that branch/bookmark into default, then merge it into compat, back it out the merge, then commit.

```
hg update default
hg merge NonCompatFeature
hg commit -m "Merging NonCompatFeature -> default."
hg update compat
hg merge NonCompatFeature
hg revert --all -r compat
hg commit -m "Merging NonCompatFeature -> compat."
```

Comment: Such dummy merges are exactly what I want to avoid but it seems not possible :) Plus, I want to keep linearity in my default branch, but I guess I could realize this if I first (no-op) merge against compat and then rebase non-compat into default.

Comment: @schlamar This is the only way I know of to do it. I wouldn't call it a dummy merge.  It's a very important merge: you're telling Mercurial "don't bring these changes into this branch". We do it regularly at my workplace.  I'm not sure what you mean by "rebase non-compat into default".

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I can think of to avoid dummy merges would be to change your workflow a little by mirroring the set up you have with the `compat` branch to add another branch to implement changes that require newer versions of Python (maybe called `latest`)

You'd implement features that are compatible with older versions of Python on `default` and merge into `compat` as you do now but also merge them into `latest`.

You'd then fix the compatibility issues on `compat` as you do now and implement features that require new features of Python on `latest` in a similar fashion.

You'd never merge from `latest` or `compat` into `default` so their changes wouldn't interfere with each other.

Comment: This has one drawback: the compat branch is (obviously) a deprecated branch, so it will be gone eventually in the future. When we now refactor our repository by stripping out the obsolete branch, we are left with two branches, which doesn't make any sense now. So maintaining two branches is much nicer if one of them should be stripped out someday.

Comment: You wouldn't strip the branch. You'd just close it and you'd close the latest branch after it was merged into default.